# using a custom compiler flag in cmake?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I'm trying to compile some code I found on GitHub https://github.com/tapio/Wendy
I'm just trying to compile the stuff in tests/. I never had any experience with cmake, but they're kinda logical anyway.

I got stuck at the part where cmake does this:

```
   /usr/bin/c++       CMakeFiles/clear.dir/clear.o  -o clear -rdynamic -lwendy -lglfw -lGLEW -lglm -lz
```

and gets this error:

```
   Linking CXX executable clear
   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwendy
   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglm
   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
   make[3]: *** [clear] Error 1
   make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/clear.dir/all] Error 2
   make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/clear.dir/rule] Error 2
   make: *** [clear] Error 2
```

I don't understand how the Wendy and glm folder became a compiler flag. Somebody please explain how this is possible. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `tests/CMakeLists.txt` the line `target_link_libraries(${test} wendy ${WENDY_LIBRARIES})` instructs cmake to link the list of libraries in `WENDY_LIBRARIES` to the executable.

Comment: Follow up question: WENDY_LIBRARIES doesn't seem to refer to anything though, and making it refer to the directory where the libraries are (~/Tapio/libs/ was what I wrote) doesn't seem to work. What should I do?

Comment: If you look in `./CMakeLists.txt` you can see that it has quite a few libraries added to it.

Comment: @Fangirl If you want to see what's in a variable, the CMake equivalent of a `printf` statement is `message`. Use it like so: `message( "libs: ${WENDY_LIBRARIES}" )`. The [cmake](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html) documentation is very thorough.